# get values from a query of a class

Tags: php

I developed a class for paging url friendly, the problem is that you can not pull the array variable to define the values ​​of the database

```
private function query($page){

    $u = Url::getURL($page);
    $numreg = $this->max_reg; // Quantos registros por página vai ser mostrado

    if (!isset($u)) {
        $u = 1;
    }

    @$inicial = $u * $this->max_reg;
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$this->table} ORDER BY id desc LIMIT $inicial, $numreg") or die(mysql_error());          
    $sql_conta = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$this->table}") or die(mysql_error());

    $out = '';

    while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($sql_conta)) {         
        $out.= $this->HTML;     
    }

    return print $out;      
}
```

so far everything is working

problem:

```
global $data;
$p = new pagination;
$p->HTML    = '
                        <li> 
                            <div class="clbthumb"><a href="#"><img src="asset/images/noticias/news4.gif" alt="" /></a></div>
                            <div class="clbdes">
                                <p class="clbtitle"><a class="colr4" href="#">'.$data['titulo'].'</a></p>  
                                <p>'.$data['texto'].'</p>
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                                <div class="clbinfo">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li class="datetag">
                                            <span class="colr3">Data:</span> 
                                            <span class="pink padr">Tue, 26/01/11</span> 
                                        <li class="moreinfo"><a href="#">:: Ler Mais</a></li>

                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>';
$p->af_HTML = '
                    </ul>
                </div>';
$p->_build(2);
```

is there any method to do this?

Comment: What's the problem?  Are you getting errors?  You're looking for a method to do something, but I'm unclear what that is.

Comment: yes I've, appears this error
Notice: Undefined variable: data in 
but when I set a global command does not appear, but does not show the query result

Comment: Where your second code section sits? is it a global code or inside a function? I assume pagination is the class containing the function query. by the information I see here, Brad's answer is correct and the global in your second code part does not do anything (variable is not declared yet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access a variable that is assigned inside a class from outside such way.
The `$data` variable in your usage (assigned to HTML) is not accessible (in your second section of code).

if you insist to set HTML from outside of your class, you can add place holders to your HTML for each variable and then replace them inside your class.

so your code will look like

```
(assuming class is pagination)

class pagination
    private function query($page){

        ...
        while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($sql_conta)) {         
            $out.= str_replace('##DATA_TITULO##', $data['titulo'] , $this->HTML, $out);
            $out.= str_replace('##DATA_TEXTO##', $data['texto'] , $this->HTML, $out);
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

and second part will be

```
$p = new pagination;
$p->HTML    = '... <a class="colr4" href="#">##DATA_TITULO##</a></p>  <p>##DATA_TEXTO##</p>...';
```

Answer (score 0):

`$data` needs to be declared global in the function where it is defined (and in any other functions that use it)

```
private function query($page){
    global $data;
    ...
}
```

Otherwise you're only setting a locally-scoped variable which happens to also be named `$data`.

It'd probably be better though if your `pagination` class had a `html($data)` function to avoid the global variable and ensure that you're getting the current values from `$data`, rather than whatever the values were when you initially set `$p->HTML`.